# How can I handle a specific warning of PySpark in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark script that get stuck for hours giving the following message unless I kill it manually:

**WARN TaskMemoryManager: Failed to allocate a page, try again**

I searched everywhere but didn't get any satisfactory answer other than increasing the driver memory. I tried that but it still won't get resolved. So I'm trying to figure out a way to handle the WARN message which when encountered, the script would auto-kill itself.

Just wondering if it can be handled by Python's Warning Control??

Comment: can you show us  your code?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather spend time addressing the cause of the warning than trying to deal with its aftermath?

Comment: @mazaneicha Our organisation is currently going through some cost related issues so I can't expect more resources to be provided for this. I have automated my whole process so restarting it is not an issue. That's why I just want to handle the warning so it auto-kills itself and restart again.

Comment: @Kulasangar It's a huge code and because of company's privacy policy I can't share it here.